# R dplyr: Use the function as a string in one column on the next column

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I want to apply a function, which name is stored in a column as a string, on a value in another column, using dplyr.
I have tried several things using `mutate_` and a `.dots` argument, but I am stuck now.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(date=as.POSIXct('2017/01/01 12:34') + 1:10*123456,
                 fun=rep(c('minute','hour','day','month','year'),2))
```

input:

```
> df
                  date    fun
1  2017-01-02 22:51:36 minute
2  2017-01-04 09:09:12   hour
3  2017-01-05 19:26:48    day
4  2017-01-07 05:44:24  month
5  2017-01-08 16:02:00   year
6  2017-01-10 02:19:36 minute
7  2017-01-11 12:37:12   hour
8  2017-01-12 22:54:48    day
9  2017-01-14 09:12:24  month
10 2017-01-15 19:30:00   year
```

output:

```
                  date    fun  res
1  2017-01-02 22:51:36 minute   51
2  2017-01-04 09:09:12   hour    9
3  2017-01-05 19:26:48    day    5
4  2017-01-07 05:44:24  month    1
5  2017-01-08 16:02:00   year 2017
6  2017-01-10 02:19:36 minute   19
7  2017-01-11 12:37:12   hour   12
8  2017-01-12 22:54:48    day   12
9  2017-01-14 09:12:24  month    1
10 2017-01-15 19:30:00   year 2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that with `do.call` but you have to use `rowwise` :

```
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.POSIXct('2017/01/01 12:34') + 1:10*123456,
  fun = rep(c('minute','hour','day','month','year'),2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(res = as.character(do.call(fun, list(date))))
```

Comment: Although I like all the other answers as well, this one comes closest to what I initially thought.

Answer (score 5):

One way , I could think of is using creating a lookup table and then getting the correct output format using `match`

```
x <- c("minute", "hour", "day", "month", "year")
y <- c("%M", "%H", "%d", "%m", "%Y")

format(df$date, format = y[match(df$fun, x)])
#[1] "51"   "09"   "05"   "01"   "2017" "19"   "12"   "12"   "01"   "2017"
```

Although, this gives a warning message but still the output is correct.

If we need this in a `dplyr` chain

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(res = format(date, format = y[match(df$fun, x)])) 


#                 date    fun   res
#1  2017-01-02 22:51:36 minute   51
#2  2017-01-04 09:09:12   hour   09
#3  2017-01-05 19:26:48    day   05
#4  2017-01-07 05:44:24  month   01
#5  2017-01-08 16:02:00   year 2017
#6  2017-01-10 02:19:36 minute   19
#7  2017-01-11 12:37:12   hour   12
#8  2017-01-12 22:54:48    day   12
#9  2017-01-14 09:12:24  month   01
#10 2017-01-15 19:30:00   year 2017
```

Comment: I like this one. Vectorization ftw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is also a very elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mapply`

```
df$res <- mapply(function(x,y) get(x)(y), as.character(df$fun), df$date)
df$res
#[1]   51    9    5    1 2017   19   12   12    1 2017
```

---

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, res := as.integer(get(as.character(fun))(date)), 1:nrow(df)]
df
#                  date    fun  res
#1: 2017-01-02 22:51:36 minute   51
#2: 2017-01-04 09:09:12   hour    9
#3: 2017-01-05 19:26:48    day    5
#4: 2017-01-07 05:44:24  month    1
#5: 2017-01-08 16:02:00   year 2017
#6: 2017-01-10 02:19:36 minute   19
#7: 2017-01-11 12:37:12   hour   12
#8: 2017-01-12 22:54:48    day   12
#9: 2017-01-14 09:12:24  month    1
#10: 2017-01-15 19:30:00   year 2017
```

NOTE: Without making any additional effort in creating look up tables

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this in a `dplyr` chain?

Comment: @Wietze314  YOu can use `map` from `purrr` which is also part of `tidyverse`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am interested in learning more about purrr (and data.table which I am postponing all the time).

Comment: I didn't know you could use `get()` with function,  I learned something here.

Answer (score 1):

To go full tidyverse here, we can use purrr's `invoke_map()` function. It takes a list of functions and a list of lists of parameter values to use for each function. It's like a vectorized `do.call()`.

The lubridate functions in `df$fun` expect an argument `x`, so we need to create a list of lists with each date stored as an element named `x`. We can create a list-column of data-frames by copying the date column and using `nest()`.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = date) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(x, .key = "params") 
df2
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>                    date    fun            params
#>                   <dttm>  <chr>           <list>
#>   1  2017-01-02 22:51:36 minute <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   2  2017-01-04 09:09:12   hour <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   3  2017-01-05 19:26:48    day <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   4  2017-01-07 05:44:24  month <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   5  2017-01-08 16:02:00   year <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   6  2017-01-10 02:19:36 minute <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   7  2017-01-11 12:37:12   hour <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   8  2017-01-12 22:54:48    day <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   9  2017-01-14 09:12:24  month <tibble [1 × 1]>
#>   10 2017-01-15 19:30:00   year <tibble [1 × 1]>
```

Each element in the column `params` is a data-frame with a column `x`. This is our list of lists.

```
df2$params[1]
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>                      x
#>                  <dttm>
#>   1 2017-01-02 22:51:36
```

With our two lists, we can use `invoke_map()` and get a list of results.

```
str(purrr::invoke_map(df2$fun, df2$params))
#> List of 10
#> $ : int 51
#> $ : int 9
#> $ : int 5
#> $ : num 1
#> $ : num 2017
#> $ : int 19
#> $ : int 12
#> $ : int 12
#> $ : num 1
#> $ : num 2017
```

But because we know that these functions return just one numeric value each, we can get the results in a nice vector with `invoke_map_dbl()`.

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(res = purrr::invoke_map_dbl(fun, params)) %>% 
  select(-params)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>                   date    fun   res
#>                 <dttm>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1  2017-01-02 22:51:36 minute    51
#> 2  2017-01-04 09:09:12   hour     9
#> 3  2017-01-05 19:26:48    day     5
#> 4  2017-01-07 05:44:24  month     1
#> 5  2017-01-08 16:02:00   year  2017
#> 6  2017-01-10 02:19:36 minute    19
#> 7  2017-01-11 12:37:12   hour    12
#> 8  2017-01-12 22:54:48    day    12
#> 9  2017-01-14 09:12:24  month     1
#> 10 2017-01-15 19:30:00   year  2017
```